# Animated Gif does not work in FireFox 18.x

Tags: jquery, asp.net, animation

I have the following code in a web page. I found that if I remove the javascript for window.location then the animated gif shows properly with animation, else it is always showing as frozen. This does not happen in IE.  Is there any fix for this?

```
       <script type="text/javascript">



        function Redirect() {

            jQuery.fn.center = function () {
                this.css("position", "absolute");
                this.css("top", ($(window).height() - this.height()) / 2 + $(window).scrollTop() + "px");
                this.css("left", ($(window).width() - this.width()) / 2 + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");
                return this;
            }


            $('#wrapperDiv').center();

            $('#imgDiv').html('<img src="../Images/ajaxLoading2.gif" alt="Loading..." />');

           $('#imgDiv').css("display", "block");

            window.location = '<%=RedirectURL %>';

        }

        $(document).ready(function () {

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you can chain events and also use `.show()` instead of manually setting the CSS to display it: `$('#imgDiv').html(...).show();`

Comment: Using show( ) method and removing the CSS for display does not help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might just be something that you cannot change.  I've seen this happen in IE in the past where it stops GIF animations when the page is being redirected.

Comment: It also works perfectly in latest Google Chrome. So FireFox is the problem here.